# CodeIgniter! Simple Ajax post request not working on localhost. Request does not show on chrome network panel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**MAJOR EDIT
This code works when hosted natively... but it is NOT working within codeigniter. I've isolated this as the problem!**

I am trying to get an ajax request to fire. I'm hosting the site locally on mac osx. Chrome network panel shows no indication that a request has been registered. I can console log static values with success as part of the same click event.

**EDIT:
I added data to be sent, added a comma and changed the trigger from an input type="submit" to an input type="button". Stil no luck. Added 'return FALSE;**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("input[name=submit]").click(function(){
    var title = $("input[name=title]").val();
    var keywords = $("input[name=keywords]").val();
    var status = $("input[name=status]").val();   
    var category = $("input[name=category]").val();
    var content = $(".note-editable").html();   

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/~mycomp/ci/admin/savetest", 
  data: {name: 'todd', age: 54},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    cache:false,

  });

    console.log(title, keywords, status, category, content);


 });

      return FALSE;

});
```

My controller is simply echoing a statement, but I haven't begun to troubleshoot this as it doesn't seem the ajax is even firing.

controller:

```
echo 'Call back';
```

Comment: You are not sending any post data - you need to set the data property. If you edit your question to include the form html, i can write an answer

Comment: try adding $.ajax( .... ).fail(function() { alert('fail'); });

Comment: neither fail, error or success will return anything. @user574632, I've added some data to send... I'd removed it in my troubleshooting, same result. I'll update my code above.

Comment: you have a syntax error, see my answer.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I had added the cache: false as a last-resort testing option. I've added a comma and no change in the result. I will update my code above. Good catch though!

Comment: Can you go to the page using just the url and the browser? make sure the url is valid.  Remember you can always just go to the url in the browser, no matter what it is. And if you can't well....

Comment: the url target? Yes, just tried and am able to view the echo

Comment: Please show the form html, and as above confirm the target url is correct

Comment: Yea you should be able to just go to it in the browser, that will tell you if the target link is bad or if its the code.

Comment: If the url is ok, then add return false for your button click handler it may be you are submitting the actual form.

Comment: @AshBrad console tab in chrome doesn't show any syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
    cache:false,
```

To ( missing comma )

```
 success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    cache:false // remove this ending comma or IE will not like you.
```

And update this too

```
$("input[name=submit]").click(function(){
    var title = $("input[name=title]").val();
    var keywords = $("input[name=keywords]").val();
    var status = $("input[name=status]").val();   
    var category = $("input[name=category]").val();
    var content = $(".note-editable").html();   

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/~mycomp/ci/admin/savetest", 
  data: {name: 'todd', age: 54},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
    cache:false,

  });

    console.log(title, keywords, status, category, content);

   return false; ///very important.
 });//end click handler.
```

Comment: updated code, and still nothing. What's strange is the chrome doesn't register anything. Is there a more simple ajax request I could try to run that would be more informative for troubleshooting?

Comment: Your sure the click handler is even running, did you try alert from just inside the click handler.

Comment: yeah. the printing to console log works fine. Also tried changing from push to get and still no indicator that request is firing. Console working fine though

Comment: change the submit button to just input type="button"

Comment: just did that:) still nothing.Also, the html is not inside of form

Comment: and the url is good your sure of that? then I dont know,  You could always change the url to the current page, window.location.href;

Comment: that's a good idea, though still nothing. It must be some deeper configuration issue. Thanks for your help though.